# Activity not working

Tags: android, android-activity

So I am using BaseGameUtils to try and get Google Games to sign in. Now I have changed my activity, but I am getting some compile errors with `setContentView()` or anything else that uses the base activity. This is what it looks like,

Error image:

[image: Error Image]

Unused Activity/Import:

[image: Unused Activity/Import]

Any advice anyone?

Comment: What does your Activity extends? What do you mean you have changed your Activity? When you hover on the red underline text, what do you get as error message?

Comment: My advice is: post more code of your activity class definition

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `BaseGameActivity`, you should override `onSetContentView()` instead of `onCreate()` and you can use `this.setContentView()` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

BaseGameActivity extends LoaderActivity. And, LoaderActivity extends Activity. 
Therefore, If you already imported BaseGameActivity, you don't need to import android.app.Activity.

If you using Eclipse, just press [**Ctrl + Shift + O**] to remove useless imported files.